# Transition to fade an element doesn't work

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-transitions

I got a problem in my code, may someone knows the solution.

I create some cards and i wanted that when i click on one of them a new bigger card appear above. I did it easily with a for loop but the problem is the transition, I'd like to set a smooth transition.

The initial state of the bigger card is `display: none;` and `opacity: 0;`
I know we can't fade a display none element, but my idea was to set first a `display: block` and then `opacity: 1` with a transition property in css in the "card-open" elements.

But the transition doesn't work and it makes my crazy because i don't know why

I share the codepen link here : https://codepen.io/arnaudhrt/pen/VwWBLze

and the javascript code :

```
const Card = document.querySelectorAll('.card')
const CardOpen = document.querySelectorAll('.card-open')
const btnClose = document.querySelectorAll('.close')


for(let i = 0 ; i < Card.length ; i++) {
  Card[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
    CardOpen[i].style.display = 'block'
    CardOpen[i].style.opacity = '1'
  });
  btnClose[i].addEventListener('click', () => {
    CardOpen[i].style.opacity = '0'
    CardOpen[i].style.display = 'none'
  })
}
```

PS: I can't set display block and just toggle the opacity because if i do that i couldn't use the other cards with the z-index.

Comment: you have to transition something. For example you can add/remove a class with opacity:1

Comment: Doesn't work sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use visibility instead display, display don't have transition effects in css.

```js
const Card = document.querySelectorAll('.card')
const CardOpen = document.querySelectorAll('.card-open')
const btnClose = document.querySelectorAll('.close')


for(let i = 0 ; i < Card.length ; i++) {
  Card[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
    CardOpen[i].style.visibility = 'visible'
    CardOpen[i].style.opacity = '1'
  });
  btnClose[i].addEventListener('click', () => {
    CardOpen[i].style.opacity = '0'
    CardOpen[i].style.visibility = 'hidden'
  })
}
```

```css
body {
  background: #565279;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
}
.container-card {
    max-width: 1200px;
    margin: auto;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    align-content: center;
    position: relative;
    transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
}
.card {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background: crimson;
    margin: 20px;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
}
.card-open {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    background: #333;
    visibility: hidden;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
}
.card-open span {
    color: #fff;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 30px;
    left: 50%;
    transform:translateX(-50%);
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-card">
      <div class="card card1"></div>
      <div class="card card2"></div>
      <div class="card card3"></div>
      <div class="card card4"></div>
      <div class="card card5"></div>
      <div class="card card6"></div>
      <div class="card card7"></div>
      <div class="card card8"></div>
      <div class="card card9"></div>
      <div class="card card10"></div>
      <div class="card-open open1"><span class="close">close</span></div>
      <div class="card-open open2"><span class="close">close</span></div>
      <div class="card-open open3"><span class="close">close</span></div>
      <div class="card-open open4"><span class="close">close</span></div>
      <div class="card-open open5"><span class="close">close</span></div>
      <div class="card-open open6"><span class="close">close</span></div>
      <div class="card-open open7"><span class="close">close</span></div>
      <div class="card-open open8"><span class="close">close</span></div>
      <div class="card-open open9"><span class="close">close</span></div>
      <div class="card-open open10"><span class="close">close</span></div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Thank you man it works perfectly, i didn't know this property 